# Change syntax to Linq to SQL lambda join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I want to switch my linq statement from query syntax to lambda,  for me the hardest part to me to understand is the `lambda join`

```
 from ru in db.rpm_usr
    join ei in db.emp_info on ru.wwid equals ei.wwid
```

So above that query join syntax is easy but when I try to put it into lambda

This is not working for me

```
  .Join(Rpm_scrty_emp_info, p => p.Iact_ind, j => j.Wwid
```

**Full query:**

```
        var queryAllUsers = (from ru in db.rpm_usr
                                  join ei in db.emp_info on ru.wwid equals ei.wwid
                                  let cdis_eml = ei.dmn_addr + ";"
                                  where ru.inact_ind == "N" && ei.inact_ind == "N" && ei.dmn_addr != null
                                  orderby ei.dmn_addr
                                  select new rpm_scrty_rpm_usr()
                                  {

                                      usr_id = ru.usr_id,
                                      usr_lnm = ru.usr_lnm,
                                      usr_pwd = ru.usr_pwd,
                                      usr_fnm = ru.usr_fnm,
                                      wwid = ru.wwid,
                                      apprvr_wwid = ru.apprvr_wwid,
                                      chg_dtm = ru.chg_dtm,
                                      chg_usr_id = ru.chg_usr_id,
                                      dflt_ste_id = ru.dflt_ste_id,
                                      cre_dtm = ru.cre_dtm,
                                      cre_usr_id = ru.cre_usr_id,
                                      lst_pwd_chg_dtm = ru.lst_pwd_chg_dtm,
                                      lst_accs_dtm = ru.lst_accs_dtm,
                                      email_id = ru.email_id,
                                      inact_ind = ru.inact_ind,
                                      salt = ru.salt,
                                      tel = ru.tel
                                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Use Linqpad and see how it converts your query to lamda syntax. For what it's worth, I always use query syntax for joins because it produces much better readable code.

Comment: I agree that I do like the query syntax more,.    there are some company standards and such ,   I do use Linqpad,  but I never find linqpad to ever really help me with the sytax,  oh does it actually show that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally find it easier to better understand LINQ in dot notation by breaking down the query onto separate lines.

Following on from @Tom's example above, the query breaks down as follows:

```
user.Join(Rpm_scrty_emp_info,  // We want to join user to Rpm_scrty_emp_info
      z => z.Wwid,             // On the left "user" side of the join we want to use the Wwid property
      ei => ei.Wwid,           // On the right "employee info" side of the join we want to use the Wwid property 
      (z, ei) => z)            // We then want to return the results on the left side of the join, i.e. our z objects
```

You can also follow @Tom's first example and leverage anonymous objects to return both sides of the join, or even specific properties.

If you don't have it already, I'd highly recommend the software, LINQpad. It's great for debugging LINQ and also has a built-in converter for switching between query and lambda syntax.

Comment: Thanks again , the explanations really help  ,.   I agree the lambda is rough to read     I'm fine with simple lambda like some i've used in .Where ,  but the .Join is ridiculous IMO ,  just a standard coding practice that I'm told to use     thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is really "worth" it as lambda joins to me are not pretty  , something like this.

I was wrong this will crate a problem with `Anonymous Type issue`

DO NOT DO THIS

```
.Join (db.emp_info,  ru => ru.wwid, ei => ei.wwid, (ru, ei) => new { ru = ru, ei = ei })
```

INSTEAD DO THIS

```
.Join(Rpm_scrty_emp_info, z => z.Wwid, ei => ei.Wwid, (z, ei) => z)
```

Comment: oh ya the second one works,  but the other guy answered it on another question i asked , thx

Comment: No problem  , the OP expained it well   take care