# Linq query throws entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a linq to entity, even when i remove the class name just using select new { ..}

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I was reading articles like this:   [Error: The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105377/error-the-entity-or-complex-type-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-qu)

So I gather that in my query I should change from `select new rpm_scrty_rpm_usr{..`   to then be `select new { ...`

Then I go from error message of

> - ex  {"The entity or complex type 'ConAppTester.rpm_scrty_rpm_usr' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."}  System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}

to instead it not compiling and getting

> Error  3   Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1> to System.Collections.Generic.List<ConAppTester.rpm_scrty_rpm_usr>  C:\dev\RLISAdmin\ConAppTester\DbMethods.cs  51  11  ConAppTester

**Method**

```
public List<rpm_scrty_rpm_usr> GetUsers()
{
    var queryAllUsers = (from ru in db.rpm_usr
                              join ei in db.emp_info on ru.wwid equals ei.wwid
                              let cdis_eml = ei.dmn_addr + ";"
                              where ru.inact_ind == "N" && ei.inact_ind == "N" && ei.dmn_addr != null
                              orderby ei.dmn_addr
                              select new rpm_scrty_rpm_usr{
                                  usr_id = ru.usr_id,
                                  usr_lnm = ru.usr_lnm,
                                  usr_pwd = ru.usr_pwd,
                                  usr_fnm = ru.usr_fnm,
                                  wwid = ru.wwid,
                                  apprvr_wwid = ru.apprvr_wwid,
                                  chg_dtm = ru.chg_dtm,
                                  chg_usr_id = ru.chg_usr_id,
                                  dflt_ste_id = ru.dflt_ste_id,
                                  cre_dtm = ru.cre_dtm,
                                  cre_usr_id = ru.cre_usr_id,
                                  lst_pwd_chg_dtm = ru.lst_pwd_chg_dtm,
                                  lst_accs_dtm = ru.lst_accs_dtm,
                                  email_id = ru.email_id,
                                  inact_ind = ru.inact_ind,
                                  salt = ru.salt,
                                  tel = ru.tel
                              }).ToList();
    return queryAllUsers;
}
```

**Context reference**

```
private RPMContext db = new RPMContext();
```

context file

```
public DbSet<rpm_scrty_rpm_usr> rpm_usr { get; set; }
public DbSet<rpm_scrty_emp_info> emp_info { get; set; }
```

POCOS

```
public class rpm_scrty_rpm_usr
{
    [Key]
    public string usr_id { get; set; }

    public string usr_fnm { get; set; }
    public string usr_lnm { get; set; }
    public string usr_pwd { get; set; }
    public string email_id { get; set; }
    public string wwid { get; set; }
    public string tel { get; set; }
    public int dflt_ste_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? lst_pwd_chg_dtm { get; set; }
    public DateTime? lst_accs_dtm { get; set; }
    public string apprvr_wwid { get; set; }
    public string inact_ind { get; set; }
    public string cre_usr_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? cre_dtm { get; set; }
    public string chg_usr_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? chg_dtm { get; set; }
    public string salt { get; set; }
}
```

Other poco

```
public class rpm_scrty_emp_info
{
    [Key]
    public string idsid { get; set; }

    public string wwid { get; set; }
    public string dmn_addr { get; set; }
    public string inact_ind { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: By the way, why do you have [two accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37470564/861716)?

Comment: co-worker and I both trying to solve problems !  :)

Comment: Why don't you just do `select ru`?

Comment: I ended up doing that   , and then I use a foreach loop ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that, as the error message says, L2E doesn't know about your entity. The way it works is that nothing happens until you enumerate the query. In your case, calling ToList() will do that. At that point, the database will try and execute the query, find it doesn't know about your entity, and give an exception.

What you need to do is construct your query in such a way that the bit that is executed on the database (ie before you enumerate) doesn't contain any reference to your entities, then after you've enumerated (by which time the results will be in memory, and detached from the database) you can create the entity.

Try the following...

```
var queryAllUsers = (from ru in db.rpm_usr
                     join ei in db.emp_info on ru.wwid equals ei.wwid
                     let cdis_eml = ei.dmn_addr + ";"
                     where ru.inact_ind == "N" && ei.inact_ind == "N" && ei.dmn_addr != null
                     orderby ei.dmn_addr
                     select ru)
                     .ToList()
                     .Select(ru => new rpm_scrty_rpm_usr {
                       usr_id = ru.usr_id,
                       usr_lnm = ru.usr_lnm,
                       usr_pwd = ru.usr_pwd,
                       usr_fnm = ru.usr_fnm,
                       wwid = ru.wwid,
                       apprvr_wwid = ru.apprvr_wwid,
                       chg_dtm = ru.chg_dtm,
                       chg_usr_id = ru.chg_usr_id,
                       dflt_ste_id = ru.dflt_ste_id,
                       cre_dtm = ru.cre_dtm,
                       cre_usr_id = ru.cre_usr_id,
                       lst_pwd_chg_dtm = ru.lst_pwd_chg_dtm,
                       lst_accs_dtm = ru.lst_accs_dtm,
                       email_id = ru.email_id,
                       inact_ind = ru.inact_ind,
                       salt = ru.salt,
                       tel = ru.tel
                     };
```

As you can see, there isn't any mention of your entities inside the brackets, so when ToList() is called, the database won't have a problem. You then create the entity in memory.

The above code is based on the fact that it looks to me as if you are just selecting `ru` as the result of your query. If you needed data from related entities, then you would need to do two selects, one as you had before (but without reference to the entity), and one after calling ToList() to create the entity.

By the way, the line `let cdis_eml = ei.dmn_addr + ";"` seems to be not needed, so you could remove it.

Hope that helps. As I'm not familiar with your database structure, it's hard to know if this is exactly what you want, so if you have any more questions, feel free to reply.

Comment: I'm not following you on this one?

Comment: @MillRunner I've updated my answer, and added some code. Sorry, was using a tablet when I typed the first reply, and it's a pain to type code on those! Hope this makes more sense.